# Send currency in push notifications via Firebase Cloud messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are able to send currency via the **Custom data** parameters in Firebase Cloud messaging (see SS below).

But if the user does not tap the notification "YOU RECEIVED 15 FREE GOLD!" then **Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived** is never fired and the user never gets their currency. So the user may see the notification, and then be disappointed the next time they open the app and there is no gold.

Is there a way in Firebase to compose the notification so that the notification can be accessed even if the user did not tap the notification to open the app?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without tapping on notification your application not launch and custom data you sent through notification is not received to the application. So sending custom data through firebase push notification is wrong choice in this scenario. You should sent custom data whatever you need through API is always good choice. You can also use firebase database and in that you can send custom data using nodes for respective user.

Comment: What do you mean by sending through API? Which feature of Firebase are you referring to? We need to be able to automatically send the gold when "Last app engagement" is more than 7 days ago. This is what the Messaging feature in Firebase allows you to do.

Comment: Where do you store the user's gold balance?  On your server somewhere?  That is what you need to update. The notification is just that.  A notification that you have added to their balance.  Or you could store a flag on their account when you send the notification and when they open the app you check for the flag. If it is set then you add the 15 gold and clear the flag. The main point is that a notification is not a data delivery mechanism.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for explaining the limitations of the Firebase Messaging Notification features. Digging into it a little more I think that the Firebase Messaging In-App Messaging will always send the message, so perhaps we can use the combination of the two.